# Stable connectivity in a high-density residential WiFi environment?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I live in a densely populated area and my devices see 10-20 wifi networks at any given time. Once in every few minutes a ping to my router goes up to the point of timeout and the device loses the connection to the wifi. I believe that it has something to do with too many networks being in the range and the router can't keep up, but I am not exactly sure that this is the root cause. I tried all usual advices, like to play with channels and nothing helps. I have 2 networks on the same router, 2.4 ghz and 5 ghz, and 2.4 one is performing worse. I forgot what the exact router is, it is TP-Link, an older model from [this line](https://www.tp-link.com/au/home-networking/dsl-modem-router/td-w9977/) (I am not using ADSL part). I am 100% sure that the wireless part is the culprit, it works perfectly fine via an Ethernet cable.

Based on this I have two questions:

1. Are connection issues related to too many wifis? How can I verify or disprove it?
2. If it is about wifis, how can I fix it? Will buying a better/newer router help?

Comment: Install a wifi analyser on your phone, it will give you some graphs of overlapping channels. See which channels are the least used and swap your router onto those.

Comment: @FiddleDeDee I did already, all channels are filled to the brim.

Answer (score 1):

1. Most likely, yes. Its not that there are to many WIFI networks as much as they are causing noise on all the channels. As there are fewer channels in the 2.4 gig band the problem will be worse.  You can get this by getting a WIFI analyzer which graphs the APs and presents the frequencies in use on a graph. (Wifi Analyzer is one such free tool for Android devices).  In the unlikely event you disprove it will be harder finding the source of noise (not all possible sources of interference are WIFI devices, but most are)
2. If your devices support it, a newer router with multiple antennas and AC standard could help. The AC standard uses corridors to cancel out echos/reflections and does channel management. You could also look at getting more directional/higher gain antennas and/or deploying more APs and smarter APs. (Look at Ubiquity gear for example).  Try.reducing your AP requirements by using Ethernet over powerline (and/or using this to connect multiple APs if ethernet is a problem).  Another method would be to get all/most WIFI users to band together and create a single, common, managed network - by doing this you prevent interference and overlapping channels and can deploy a larger, more robust.network - but this is not easy.

Comment: I used Wifi Analyser, channels are pretty full, that's why I am quite certain that this is the root cause. Also somehow not so many channels are available for 5ghz, might something to do with regulations (EU), or router having old list or something.

Comment: Regarding 2, thanks, I will look into it. I can't control other people's APs unfortunately. I myself have only one AP (the router) so I don't really need a large network for now.

Comment: Just be aware that 2 APs in seperate positions on different frequencies will increase the signal to noise ratio in the vicinity of the APs.

Comment: That's something new to me, do you know where can I read further about it?

Comment: My initial searches for more information on this (at the appropriate technical level), however the topic is amenable to a simple thought experiment.  In the ways that matter here, the problem is no different to people trying to communicate in a noisy environment.  People need to talk more loudly and/or get closer together to hear each other, the person you are trying to hear is the signal, the background sound is the noise.  The louder the person speaks relative to the background the more easily you can here them.

Comment: Tangentially related/useful reading - https://www.cnet.com/news/diagnosing-and-addressing-wi-fi-signal-quality-problems/ https://www.metageek.com/training/resources/adjacent-channel-congestion.html